# "Alien did it" tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

I've been noticing more and more questions along the lines "aliens did [this silly complex magic thing], what would happen?".

Could we please create a tag for them?

It should encompass all posts of this kinds, even if it wasn't aliens' fault specifically, such as "suddenly [this silly unexplainable thing] happened for apparently no reason, what now?".

Comment: I think a better term could be "what-if" (serves both to "what if aliens"/"what if a wizard")

Comment: @SJuan76 I think a "what-if" tag would tend to invite answers derived from XKCD's [What-If?](http://what-if.xkcd.com/) section. Not that it isn't used a lot already, of course. :)

Comment: It's really just because of a series of questions by one user, and [there's a different reason](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18440/aliens-put-us-on-the-moon#comment45131_18440).

Comment: @HDE226868 not only by one user, I've seen other such post (though him has definitely worsened the situation). Maybe [tag:hand-weave], to be assigned to post with very strong hand-weaves?

Comment: I think this is just something we should expect, as long as it's not tagged [tag:reality-check]. A lot of questions start from an impossible or hand-wavey premise and ask for the effects, I don't think it'll be easy categorizing them and then enforcing that categorization.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I disagree. I'd expect better thought-out questions, which steam from serious attempt to build credible worlds. Instead we've recently been flooded with very silly "stuff happens for no reason, what then" which have blatantly no purpose other than having an idle chat. This is a very serious problem: if not addressed, it could easily kill this site.

Comment: @Lohoris In that case, we definitely shouldn't make a tag for it :L

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh well, yes, just closing them would be much better. But if for some suicidal reason we decide not to close them, at least a tag to filter them out could be a start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**I disagree with creating a tag for this purpose.**

Tags should be used to categorize content. Ideally, saying "I am an expert in tag-name" should pass the laugh test. We have a few meta tags (science-based, hard-science, reality-check, and perhaps a few others) which pass this test only because *they aren't supposed to be used in isolation;* a question can't be *just* science-based, though it can be for example science-based evolution. In this sense, our such tags are similar to for example Stack Overflow's language-lawyer tag, which also can't really be used in isolation.

However, nobody is going to say seriously and with a straight face "I am an expert in alien-did-it", or any variation thereof. Nor are they going to say "I am an expert in alien-did-it dragons".

Since you also said in a comment:

> I'd expect better thought-out questions, which steam from serious attempt to build credible worlds. Instead we've recently been flooded with very silly "stuff happens for no reason, what then" which have blatantly no purpose other than having an idle chat. This is a very serious problem: if not addressed, it could easily kill this site.

Creating a tag for questions that you feel do not belong on the site in the first place is *absolutely* **the wrong path to take.** If anything, creating a tag indicates to people that the type of question covered by the tag *is* welcomed by the community, at least to some level. If you feel these types of questions are off topic, you should be flagging them as off topic, bring it up on Meta (we have a quite active community on our Meta, especially for a beta site), or bring it up in chat to try to gain a community consensus. All of these options are available to almost everyone with an account on the site, with the possible exception of chat which [requires 20 reputation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) (which frankly isn't very hard to get on Worldbuilding; a single half-way-decent answer will likely get you there).

We have had significant discussions both in chat and here on Meta early during the beta period about what types of questions we accept, which has been summarized in [the help center's page on what topics are on-topic for us](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); the [on-topic tag](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/on-topic) here on Meta captures some of this. Our subject here at Worldbuilding, almost by definition, is going to be a lot less about right or wrong answers than, say, Stack Overflow, but that doesn't mean we don't have quality standards for content, only that our standards are *different* from those of the trilogy sites in particular.

**One of the main ways in which Worldbuilding differs from many other sites** is that we accept questions stating preconditions that cannot happen in the real world, which answers are expected to take into account. We have questions involving [dragons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon), [Ragnarök](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ragnarok), [teleportation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teleportation), [shapeshifters](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapeshifter), [miscellaneous mythical creatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythical-creatures) like centaurs, [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) and so on and so forth. [We even have an *actual* question about unicorns.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4764/29) This *allows* for questions that handwave away how a situation came to be (so you don't even really need to say in your question "an alien did it" about how unicorns evolved in your world; if you state that unicorns exist, answerers are to assume that unicorns do exist), while asking for answers to *what will happen* in that situation.

Comment: OK, this is a good point, but then do you have any suggestion on how to define those silly questions in order to define them as OT? or do you think they should stay?

Comment: @Lohoris If you think they are off topic under any of the existing close reasons, you should flag as such and the community will take a look at them (our review queues are normally empty or nearly so). If they don't fit into any of the currently existing close reasons but you feel they should be off topic, then open a meta discussion post about that. A moderator's role in this case is to enforce community standards, not set them, and *this* question is about creating a tag (not whether the questions are on-topic or not).