# Tags to identify flexibility of questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Due to the nature of WorldBuilding, the details of a specific world are changeable and therefore subject to discussion and improvement. This can lead to debates on whether a certain technology is effective or not *in this world* or whether *this world* should utilise a certain feature.

In some cases this is great because the owner of the world is open to new suggestions and revising their world or adding to it. They don't mind whether answers provide a solution to their problem or adjust the details of the world to remove the problem.

In other cases, the owner is set on their world and does not want the details to be discussed; they just want an answer based on a scenario that they have already finalised. In this case they purely want a solution and do not want alternate suggestions.

Would it be useful to have tags to identify how flexible a user's post is?

Of course, it is completely possible that the OP could simply put in the question whether it is open for scrutiny, however I think that tags would be simpler and more widely used.

Comment: Meta tags are generally something to avoid. We already use tags like [tag:science-based]. If we add more meta tags we quickly reach the limit of five tags at most without having said anything about the content. And tags are supposed to be about the content. See [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/28789) for an answer on a different request about a new meta tag for questions. Also you should try to focus on whether you want a discussion or a feature-request. First you should try to start a discussion and after getting the sentiment of the community make a featuer-request

Comment: @Secespitus That should be an answer really :)

Comment: @TimB I didn't have time to write a full answer when I wrote that comment. This question also already has an accepted answer so I am not sure if I really need to expand that comment into a full answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't need tags to do this.

There already exists an expectation that answers work within the premise of the question being asked. If I ask "How do space pilots orient themselves in space?" an answer of "Space magic." or "Don't use a space pilot, use a space AI." doesn't provide an answer to the question asked. If there are some obvious answers that you don't want people to consider, be sure to clearly state those restrictions in the premise.